# How execution time of code instructions influences signal between Arduino and DHT11?

Tags: pulsein, dht11

I am exemining code for DHT11 from CircuitGeeks, variant without using lib. The problem is a mismatch between DHT11/DHT22 protocol and signals, which are read from sensor in scetch. Despite this, sketch is working and I would like to find out how.

```
#define DHT11_PIN   12

unsigned long TON_TIME = 0;
unsigned long TOFF_TIME = 0;

unsigned char data_byte[5];
unsigned int data_packet[40];
unsigned char bit_data = 0;
unsigned char checksum_byte = 0;
int bit_counter = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("DHT11 Humidity & Temperature Sensor\n");
  delay(1000);//Wait before accessing Sensor
}

void loop() {
  pinMode(DHT11_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(DHT11_PIN, LOW);
  delay(18);
  digitalWrite(DHT11_PIN, HIGH);
  pinMode(DHT11_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);

  TOFF_TIME = pulseIn(DHT11_PIN, LOW);
  if (TOFF_TIME <= 84 && TOFF_TIME >= 76) {
    while (1) {
      TON_TIME = pulseIn(DHT11_PIN, HIGH);
      if (TON_TIME <= 28 && TON_TIME >= 20) {
        bit_data = 0;
      }
      else if (TON_TIME <= 74 && TON_TIME >= 65) {
        bit_data = 1;
      }
      else if (bit_counter == 40) {
        break;
      }
      data_byte[bit_counter / 8] |= bit_data << (7 - (bit_counter % 8));
      data_packet[bit_counter] = bit_data;
      bit_counter++;
    }
  }
  checksum_byte = data_byte[0] + data_byte[1] + data_byte[2] + data_byte[3];

  if (checksum_byte == data_byte[4] && checksum_byte != 0) {
    Serial.println("Humidity: ");
    for (int c = 0; c <= 7; c++) {
      Serial.print(data_packet[c]);
    }
    Serial.print("\t");
    for (int c = 0; c <= 7; c++) {
      Serial.print(data_packet[c + 8]);
    }
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(data_byte[0]);
    Serial.print("%");
    Serial.println(" ");

    Serial.println("Temperature: ");
    for (int c = 0; c <= 7; c++) {
      Serial.print(data_packet[c + 16]);
    }
    Serial.print("\t");
    for (int c = 0; c <= 7; c++) {
      Serial.print(data_packet[c + 24]);
    }
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(data_byte[2]);
    Serial.print("C");
    Serial.println(" ");

    Serial.println("Checksum Byte: ");
    for (int c = 0; c <= 7; c++) {
      Serial.print(data_packet[c + 32]);
    }
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.print("CHECKSUM_OK");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("");
  }

  bit_counter = 0;
  data_byte[0] = data_byte[1] = data_byte[2] = data_byte[3] = data_byte[4] = 0;
  delay(1000);
}
```

Looking into the code there is 18 ms of LOW level for initialization. Then about 40 us of HIGH level, it can be considered as time between `digitalWrite(DHT11_PIN, HIGH);` and `TOFF_TIME = pulseIn(DHT11_PIN, LOW);` instructions. But then after 80 us of LOW level `TOFF_TIME = pulseIn(DHT11_PIN, LOW);` it should be 80 us HIGH level. Instead of this, the code is being continued by conditions for checking pulses length, which are responsable for data bits. If pulse length is 26-28 us it's 0, if 70 us - it's 1. I understand that with `TON_TIME = pulseIn(DHT11_PIN, HIGH);` instruction we will find length of HIGH pulses of data bits only. 
[image]

Why 80 us HIGH level is passed, however this doesn't impact on interaction with sensor? Does it pass in time of executing instructions from  `if (TOFF_TIME <= 84 && TOFF_TIME >= 76)` to `TON_TIME = pulseIn(DHT11_PIN, HIGH);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the 80 µs LOW from the HDT11, `pulseIn(DHT11_PIN, LOW)`
returns. At this point in time, the data line is HIGH, somewhere near
the beginning of the positive 80 µs pulse. Now, the code executes the
first `pulseIn(DHT11_PIN, HIGH)`.

You cannot measure the length of a positive pulse if you missed the
rising edge. Thus, as `pulseIn()` finds the line HIGH, it will first
wait until it transition to LOW, then wait until in transitions back to
HIGH, and only then starting timing.

See for example the [implementation of the counting loop in the AVR
core](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.6/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.S), or rather the C code that served to generate the assembly
implementation. It has three waiting loops:

- wait for any previous pulse to end
- wait for the pulse to start
- wait for the pulse to stop